# Magento2 : knock out js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I would like to changes in **checkout page address fields**,

how to **remove** the fields or **update**, the code is **knockout js**.

How to **modify** this.

```
<div class="address-information address-info-3-columns">
                    <div id='opcheckout-shipping-section'>
                        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('steps') -->
                            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shipping-step') -->
                                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shipping-address') -->
                                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                                <!--/ko-->
                            <!--/ko-->
                        <!--/ko-->
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add more description

Comment: hi vivek, we need to remove and change some text fields in shipping address section

Comment: Please add some code you tried/ files you found out were responsible for the fields.

Comment: it is calling from app\code\vendor\module\view\frontend\web\template\opcheckout.html file this is in knockout js

Comment: Please add the code of the file and all the required information in question itself.

Comment: please find the updated question, i need to remove comany and update the street name

Comment: Are you removing company name right?

Comment: Admin side setting available for this. Go to admin: Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options

Comment: @shivashankarm did you get your solution??? actually I'm trying to override `list.html` file which is the html of of checkout can you please let me know how to override the `list.html` file of checkout?